# I am seeing DeprecationWarning: executable_path has been deprecated, please pass in a Service object

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

from selenium import webdriver
import selenium

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\Users\ASUS\Downloads\driver\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("http://wwww.google.com")
print(driver.title)

Chrome browser launch but displays error This site can’t be reached check if there is a typo in wwww.google.com.
If the spelling is correct, try running Windows Network Diagnostics.
DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN